# Decouple Authorisation server and resource server with RemoteTokenServices

Tags: oauth, spring-security

I am trying spring security and spring oauth2 in my project and have separated my authorization server and resource server. I didn't want to share a token store between these two servers so I decided to use RemoteTokenServices and the check_token endpoint. Everything was fine except when I used an access token to query the resource server, I got "401 Unauthorized" error as follows:

2015-10-19 11:50:10.291 DEBUG 2590 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : POST request for "http://localhost:9080/uaa/oauth/check_token/" resulted in 401 (Unauthorized); invoking error handler
2015-10-19 11:50:10.293 DEBUG 2590 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2015-10-19 11:50:10.293 DEBUG 2590 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.filter.RequestContextFilter      : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@41f4867a
2015-10-19 11:50:10.297 ERROR 2590 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[jerseyServlet]        : Servlet.service() for servlet [jerseyServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)

The code for the Authorisation server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuthConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
        return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultAccessTokenConverter defaultAccessTokenConverter() {
        return new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(this.tokenStore())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .accessTokenConverter(defaultAccessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)
            throws Exception {
        oauthServer
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

}
```

And the security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication();
//            .withUser("John").roles("ADMIN").password("password")
//            .and()
//            .withUser("Mary").roles("BASIC").password("password");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic().realmName("OAuth Server");
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

The Resource Server is set up as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private static String RESOURCE_ID = "xn-resource-id"; 

    private TokenExtractor tokenExtractor = new BearerTokenExtractor();


    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        return new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices(final @Value("${auth.server.url}") String checkTokenUrl,
            final @Value("${auth.server.client_id}") String clientId,
            final @Value("${auth.server.client_secret}") String clientSecret) {
        final RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
        remoteTokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(checkTokenUrl);
        remoteTokenServices.setClientId(clientId);
        remoteTokenServices.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        remoteTokenServices.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
        return remoteTokenServices;
    }
}
```

I tested the security settings with curl and used client_credentials grant type.

Does anyone help me figure out what's the issue with the above code?

Comment: did you get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using incorrect url. Try to repleace it with:

```
 http://localhost:9080/uaa/oauth/check_token
```

(notice that url is not ended with **/**)